# AuthenticationScheme & IAuthenticationHandler

Tags: asp.net-core

Hope everyone keeping safe,

I am trying to understand some of the abstractions in asp.net core authentication / authorization (and browsing the source code for additional insight).

There is an abstraction called "AuthenticationScheme" which seems to only bring in a ‘name’ property to the actual IAuthenticationHandler (which seems to be  is the type that does the work).

I am trying to understand why asp.net has this the scheme abstraction, if the intent is just to give the handler a name, why not just include a name property in the handler's interface definition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow usage of the handler multiple times at least.

If you make an API that allows JWT Bearer tokens from two identity providers, then you might want to specify the JWT Bearer authentication handler twice.
And since each handler needs a unique name so we can invoke the right one, the developer must define those names.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, but I am still a bit confused..... If we have a situation like the one you are describing with an api that allows either of two JWT from identity providers, how many AuthenticationScheme and how many AuthenticationHandler would be required ?

Comment: You'd use two, something like `AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer("Jwt1", options => {}).AddJwtBearer("Jwt2", options => {})`.